# Неправильно срабатывает условие, как будто выполняется 2 раза

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Почему неправильно срабатывает условие? Если я ввожу html_name которого не существует, то он создает файл с этим именем, выводит success но тут же переключается и выводит errorest. Почему? Как будто запрос отправляется второй раз. Что нужно прописать чтобы он нормально работал?

```
<?php
$result = [];
$title=$_POST['titles'];
$text=$_POST['txt'];
$html_name=$_POST['html_name'];
$filename = 'news/'.$html_name.'.html';
if (file_exists($filename)){
    $result['message3'] = 'errorest';
    exit(json_encode($result)); // Выходим и превращаем массив $result в json
}
else
{
$f = fopen('news/'.$html_name.'.html', "w"); 
fwrite($f, $strOuthtm); 
fclose($f); 
$result['message1'] = 'success'; 
exit(json_encode($result));
}
?>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST', // Тип запроса
  url: 'handler.php', // Скрипт обработчика
  data: formData, // Данные которые мы передаем
  cache:false, // В запросах POST отключено по умолчанию, но перестрахуемся
  contentType: false, // Тип кодирования данных мы задали в форме, это отключим
  processData: false, // Отключаем, так как передаем файл
  success:function(data){
   var res = JSON.parse(data); // Парсим json
        if (res.message3 == 'errorest') {
        $('#result').text(res.message3);
        $('#result').show();
        } 
        if (res.message1 == 'success') {
        $('#result').text(res.message1);
        $('#result').show();
        }

  }
});
```

Comment: А как вы вызываете AJAX? Откройте `devTools` и посмотрите во вкладке `Network` - может действительно, запрос уходит два раза.

Comment: Действительно, запрос срабатывает почему-то два раза. В Network появляется один POST с ответом success и после него идет второй уже с errorest.
Перед ajax вызывается так   
$('#upload-image').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    var formData = new FormData(this);
 
**HTML:** <button class="button-send button" type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button>

Comment: Скорее всего вы навешиваете два раза обработчик события `submit`. Когда выполняется `$('#upload-image').on('submit'...`?

Comment: Разобрался. Это было так супер глупо. Оказывается я два раза вызывал этот скрипт... Но теперь возникла еще одна проблема. Поле textarea почему-то не передается с первого раза, нужно после нажатия изменять название чтобы добавить новую новость и только тогда, после повторного нажатия, он передает данные

Comment: Что бы вам помочь, надо видеть весь код) Как видите ошибка может быть в таком месте, в котором и не станешь искать сначала.